# Google Analytics event works in Developer Console but not in page

Tags: events, google-analytics, event-tracking

I have this code in my product page after an item has been added to cart:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
//<![CDATA[

    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(ga);
    })();

    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'Page Type', 'Product', 3])
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 2, 'Product Name', 'Gold Bracelet', 3]);
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Product Page', 'Added To Basket', 'Gold Bracelet', , 0]); // this is the line that isn't working.

        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);


//]]>
</script>
```

It seems the pageview is tracked, the two custom variables, but not the _trackEvent. Like I said in the title, if I copy and paste this code into Chrome Dev Console, the events show up just fine. I added an alert() to the code that returns the _trackPageview and it worked, so the JS is definitely getting parsed.

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Did you read this: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables ?

Comment: Just wondering – `…, 'Gold Bracelet', , 0]` – is that on purpose, that there seems to be a value “missing” before the 0?

Comment: Bodi - that article is mostly to do with Custom Variables, which are working fine. The issue I'm having is with the trackEvent call.

Comment: CBroe - that argument is optional.

Comment: I don't think that's how optional arguments work - you can omit them from right to left, but a double comma followed by another parameter will produce a syntax error. You should try and set this to 0 (or null for string values).

Comment: Don't use quotes around `undefined` for any optional parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `opt_value` parameter isn't an integer (or undefined), the event won't be recorded.

Do you want this event to affect bounce rate calculations? If so, the `opt_noninteraction` can be left off since the default value is `false`:

```
 _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Product Page', 'Added To Basket', 'Bodysuit...']);
```

If you don't want the event to affect the bounce rate, use:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Product Page', 'Added To Basket', 'Bodysuit...', undefined, true]);
```

---

I missed this in my first look at your code -- since `_trackEvent` is before `_setAccount`, the data it sends get's recorded to a default account (something like 'UA-XXXXX-X').

Move the `_trackEvent` call anywhere after `_setAccount`.

Also, since you've got both `_trackEvent` and `_trackPageview` in the same block of code, you'll want to be sure that the `opt_noninteraction` parameter is true.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Weird that the code works when I run it manually though. I'll change it and see if it fixes it.

Comment: I changed it to: _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Product Page', 'Added To Basket', 'Flash Choker by Scott Wilson for Aqua - Gold', 0 , 0]); - Nothing is reporting still. BTW, I do want this event to affect the bounce rate calculation.

Comment: What happens right after the `_trackEvent`? Are you visiting a new page?

Comment: No, it's called along with the rest of the script as the page loads. It's not bound to a js click or anything.

Comment: Does it have to be bound to JS events? Is that my issue?

Comment: I just took a closer look at your code -- `_trackEvent` needs to be called after `_setAccount`.

Comment: You are a legend! That explains why it worked when I ran the code manually. _setAccount had already been called when the page loaded.